# Obter arquivo JSON de uma API

Tags: c#, api, webrequest

Estou começando a entender sobre API porém estou com uma grande dificuldade, pois tentando consumir um JSON de uma API conforme o código abaixo:

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url + api);
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Timeout = 30000;
        request.ReadWriteTimeout = 30000;

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var jsonReturn = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            dynamic dobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonReturn);
        }
```

Porém desta forma esta dando erro (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.')

Debugando o código notei que a `var jsonReturn` está em trazendo um arquivo `HTML` e no `dynamic dobj` está dando o erro citado a cima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o que está acontecendo é que a aplicação está retornando um erro em html e não um json, por isso o Newtonsoft não consegue deserializar já que o retorno é uma string e não um json.

tente validar o status code para garantir que só irá deserializar se o status for sucesso.

Comment: Muito obrigado Cristiano, me ajudou bastante sua resposta.